# Evalute $\frac{\tan\alpha-\cot\alpha}{\sin^4\alpha-\cos^4\alpha}$ if $\tan\alpha=2$

Tags: trigonometry

Evalute $\dfrac{\tan\alpha-\cot\alpha}{\sin^4\alpha-\cos^4\alpha}$ if $\alpha$ is an acute angle and $\tan\alpha=2.$

Can you give me a hint? We can factor the denominator, but I don't think it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With openspace's idea:

$$\dfrac{\tan\alpha-\cot\alpha}{\sin^4\alpha-\cos^4\alpha} = \frac{\tan\alpha-\cot\alpha}{\cos^4 \alpha(\tan^4 \alpha  -1)} = \frac{\tan \alpha - \cot \alpha}{1/(1 + \tan^2 \alpha)^2 \cdot(\tan^4 \alpha  -1)} = \frac{2 - 1/2}{1/5^2 \cdot 15} = \boxed{\frac{5}{2}}.$$

Answer (score 5):

*Hints*: $\tan(a) = \dfrac{1}{\cot(a)}$, $\cos^2(a) = \dfrac{1}{1+\tan^2(a)}$ and $\sin^2(a) = \dfrac{1}{1+\cot^2(a)}$

Comment: I haven't seen the second and the third formula. How can I get them?

Comment: @10thgrade $\sin^2 + \cos^2 = 1$ then divide by $\sin^2$ or $\cos^2$

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

Factorizing the denominator and using the fact that $\ {\sin}^{2}a+{\cos}^{2}a=1$, we have
$$\ \dfrac{\tan\alpha-\cot\alpha}{\sin^4\alpha-\cos^4\alpha}=\dfrac{\tan\alpha-\cot\alpha}{\sin^2\alpha-\cos^2\alpha}={\sec}^{2}\alpha\dfrac{\tan\alpha-\cot\alpha}{\tan^2\alpha-1}=({\tan}^{2}\alpha+1)\dfrac{\tan\alpha-\cot\alpha}{\tan^2\alpha-1}=(4+1)\frac{(2-\frac{1}{2})}{4-1}=\frac{5}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

It's very useful to draw a small triangle to help you think about the trigo stuff:[image]

and the fact that $\cot \alpha = 1/(\tan \alpha) = 1/2, \sin^4 \alpha = (\sin \alpha)^4, \cos^4 \alpha = (\cos \alpha)^4$.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{\tan\alpha - \cot\alpha}{\sin^4\alpha - \cos^4\alpha}=\frac{\frac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha}-\frac{\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha}}{(\sin^2\alpha - \cos^2\alpha)(\sin^2\alpha + \cos^2\alpha)}=\frac{\frac{\sin^2\alpha - \cos^2\alpha}{\sin\alpha \cos\alpha}}{\sin^2\alpha - \cos^2\alpha}=\frac{1}{\sin\alpha \cos\alpha}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+\cot^2\alpha}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+\tan^2\alpha}}}=$

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{4}}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+4}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{4}{5}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{5}}}=\boxed{\frac{5}{2}}.$